# Recipe openldap doesn't install ldapsearch utility into a yocto-base Linux distribution

Tags: linux, yocto, openldap, yocto-recipe

I have successfully added the recipe `openldap` to my yocto-base Linux distribution, by the instruction:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "openldap"
```

After that I've created a `path/to/my-layer/recipes-support/openldap/openldap_%.bbappend` file and put in it the instruction:

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "already-stripped"
```

Without the previous instruction the compilation of `openldap` fails.
Conversely by adding the previous assignment to the variable `INSANE_SKIP_${PN}`,  the QA checks stop failing.

### My real problem

The compilation process produces the binary file for the utility `ldapsearch` but this file isn't installed into the image.
Instead I'm sure that `openldap` results correctly installed.

I don't find any method to add `ldapsearch` to the image.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have successfully added the recipe openldap to my Yocto image, by
> the instruction:
>
> `IMAGE_INSTALL += "openldap"`

You've added the *package* openldap to your image. The recipe however defines multiple packages:

```
# The executables go in a separate package.  This allows the
# installation of the libraries with no daemon support.
# Each module also has its own package - see above.
PACKAGES += "${PN}-slapd ${PN}-slurpd ${PN}-bin"

# Package contents - shift most standard contents to -bin
FILES:${PN} = "${libdir}/lib*.so.* ${sysconfdir}/openldap/ldap.* ${localstatedir}/${BPN}/data"
FILES:${PN}-slapd = "${sysconfdir}/init.d ${libexecdir}/slapd ${sbindir} ${localstatedir}/run ${localstatedir}/volatile/run \
    ${sysconfdir}/openldap/slapd.* ${sysconfdir}/openldap/schema \
    ${sysconfdir}/openldap/DB_CONFIG.example ${systemd_unitdir}/system/*"
FILES:${PN}-slurpd = "${libexecdir}/slurpd ${localstatedir}/openldap-slurp"
FILES:${PN}-bin = "${bindir}"
...
```

You likely want to add `openldap-bin` to your image.

Comment: Thanks I have changed to `IMAGE_INSTALL += "openldap openldap-bin" ` so in my image are present all the utility.